# Dynamically create list of classes with inheritance and classmethods

Tags: python, inheritance, dynamic, python-2.7, class-method

I have a list of classes, and I'm trying to dynamically create another list of classes, such that each one has a `classmethod` that creates an instance of a child of a class from the original list.
The problem is that all the methods end up returning an instance of the same class (the last one created).

Here is a minimized version of my code:

```
class C1():
    var = 1
class C2():
    var = 2

parents = (C1, C2)
children = []
wrappers = []

for c in parents:

    class ChildClass(c):
        pass
    children.append(ChildClass())

    class Wrapper():
        @classmethod
        def method(cls):
            cls.wrapped = ChildClass()

    wrappers.append(Wrapper)

print(list(child.var for child in children))

for wrapper in wrappers:
    wrapper.method()

print(list(wrapper.wrapped.var for wrapper in wrappers))
```

The output:

```
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
```

You can see that the `children` list contains different instances, while the `classmethod` creates an instance of a child of `C2` in both cases.

How can I fix my code so that each `classmethod` creates an instance of the correct class?

(I'm using python 2.7.4)

Comment: What's the problem to which is this a solution?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - I'm testing a web application using `unittest`. I have a base tester class, and I'm creating a child class for each browser (Firefox, IE, etc...). Each child class needs a `setUpClass` (which is a `classmethod`) that creates an instance of a selenium `WebDriver` for its browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ChildClass` reference in the `Wrapper.method()` is a free variable, meaning it'll be resolved when `Wrapper.method()` is called, *not* when the method is defined.

By the time you call that method, the name `ChildClass` will refer to the last class you created.

You either need to provide a scope that has only one unambiguous value for `ChildClass`, or otherwise bind the reference at definition time. The latter can be done by using a function parameter default:

```
class Wrapper():
    @classmethod
    def method(cls, child_class=ChildClass):
        cls.wrapped = child_class()
```

You can also use a function scope to bind the reference to a local variable in that scope:

```
def createClasses(parent):
    class ChildClass(parent):
        pass

    class Wrapper():
        @classmethod
        def method(cls):
            cls.wrapped = ChildClass()

    return ChildClass, Wrapper

for c in parents:
    child, wrapper = createClasses(c)

    children.append(child)
    wrappers.append(wrapper)
```

Here, when `Wrapper.method` refers to `ChildClass`, it'll be looked up in the local namespace of the `createClasses` function, and there is only ever going to be one value bound to that name.